# Bluehost cloud hosting, varnish caching issue authenticated user

Tags: 7, caching, proxies

I have narrowed down my problem to varnish on my cloud server provided from bluehost.

When logged in you make an edit, but it is not reflected back until 5-10 minutes later.

Clearing all caches, browser history, etc. nothing helps expect logging into bluehost and clearing the varnish cache.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add that varnish **only work for anonymous user** not for authenticated.

There are various module available to purge varnish cached data on a particular event such as node insert, update, delete and many more.

Configure events properly in module configuration and that should do the needful.

Following are module :

[expire](https://www.drupal.org/project/expire)

[purge](https://www.drupal.org/project/purge)